# IDE for AngularJS development with debugging, code complete and profiling capabilities?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs

What IDE would you recommend for AngularJS, or even JavaScript development in general that has similar features like Eclipse for Java based development?

I have done some research on google, but the discussions are mostly outdated and wanted to check in SO to get a more relevant recommendation.

Any help or tips would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [webstorm](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ide)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebStorm is the best for Javascript, AngularJs and web development in general. You can create lot of user defined code helpers and can create controllers e.t.c easily with that.

Comment: +1 on WebStorm, its the only one that's worked well for me.. Visual Studio 2013 also does this pretty well, but IMO webstorm is superior.

Comment: Thank you. WebStorm seems to be unanimous choice. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use Eclipse and install angularjs-eclipse, see  https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

[image]

[image]

I am co-author of [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) and Enide Studio, and we are working with Angelo (author of angularjs-eclipse) on including that plugin into [Enide Studio](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/). Also guys from JBoss expressed desire to include this plugin into JBoss Developer Studio, ref [#28](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/28)